# get data from browser using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to get data from a URL using selenium.
I've also added `chromedriver` and `selenium-java-4.0.0-beta-2` in my project.

when I run the project I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/NoHttpResponseException
    
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException
```

Code :

```
package readdata;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class test_Selenium {

    public void testGoogleSearch() throws InterruptedException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\.....\\lib\\exe\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.navigate().to("http://www.javatpoint.com/");
        
    }
}
```

Comment: How does your classpath look like?

Comment: （ARIGATO-for your response）how can i verify the classpath?? i'm using NetBeans

Comment: Do you use Maven or Gradle?

Comment: i don't use anything as build tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error is caused as there is no selenium jar in your classpath.

If You are using Maven as your build tool, you may need to include below dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
<version>4.0.0-alpha-1</version>
</dependency>
```

if you are using Gradle as your build tool then you need to use below dependency

```
compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '4.0.0-alpha-1'
```

Comment: thinks a lot ,it's the first time i use maven ,and it's an amazing tool